# tflite-model-maker custom dataset (pascal voc) problem - ValueError: The size of the train_data (0) couldn't be smaller than the batch_size (1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I've recently been trying to follow the tutorial here: https://colab.research.google.com/github/google-coral/tutorials/blob/master/retrain_efficientdet_model_maker_tf2.ipynb#scrollTo=ZljJ25RAnj5x

However, I'm running this on a workstation, not in Google Colab.

I've reduced the code down to the bare minimum as shown here:

```py
import numpy as np
import os
import random
import shutil

from tflite_model_maker.config import ExportFormat
from tflite_model_maker import model_spec
from tflite_model_maker import object_detector

import tensorflow as tf
assert tf.__version__.startswith('2')

tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')
from absl import logging
logging.set_verbosity(logging.ERROR)
  
label_map = {1: 'TIE', 2: 'HOLE'} 

train_images_dir = '/home/dev/Tensorflow/workspace/tpu_vision/tpu_images/training/images/'
train_annotations_dir = '/home/dev/Tensorflow/workspace/tpu_vision/tpu_images/training/annotations/'
val_images_dir = '/home/dev/Tensorflow/workspace/tpu_vision/tpu_images/validation/images/'
val_annotations_dir = '/home/dev/Tensorflow/workspace/tpu_vision/tpu_images/validation/annotations/'
test_images_dir = '/home/dev/Tensorflow/workspace/tpu_vision/tpu_images/test/images/'
test_annotations_dir = '/home/dev/Tensorflow/workspace/tpu_vision/tpu_images/test/annotations/'

train_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(train_images_dir, train_annotations_dir, label_map=label_map)
validation_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(val_images_dir, val_annotations_dir, label_map=label_map)
test_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(test_images_dir, test_annotations_dir, label_map=label_map)

print(f'train count: {len(train_data)}')
print(f'validation count: {len(validation_data)}')
print(f'test count: {len(test_data)}')

spec = object_detector.EfficientDetLite1Spec()

model = object_detector.create(train_data=train_data, model_spec=spec, validation_data=validation_data, epochs=10000, batch_size=1, train_whole_model=True)

model.evaluate(test_data)

TFLITE_FILENAME = 'efficientdet-lite.tflite'
LABELS_FILENAME = 'labels.txt'

model.export(export_dir='.', tflite_filename=TFLITE_FILENAME, label_filename=LABELS_FILENAME,export_format=[ExportFormat.TFLITE, ExportFormat.LABEL])
             
model.evaluate_tflite(TFLITE_FILENAME, test_data)
```

My image directories are full of only images, and I've ensured that they are properly formatted JPG files.

Likewise, my annotations directories are pascal voc format XML files. I used [labelImg](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg) to make the annotations.

Running the above code produces the following error:

```
(venv) dev@trainingpc:~/Tensorflow/workspace/tpu_vision$ python3 train.py 
2021-11-18 16:02:07.008550: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
train count: 0
validation count: 0
test count: 0
2021-11-18 16:02:08.950882: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2021-11-18 16:02:08.983851: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-11-18 16:02:08.984135: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:2c:00.0 name: NVIDIA RTX A6000 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.8GHz coreCount: 84 deviceMemorySize: 47.54GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 715.34GiB/s
2021-11-18 16:02:08.984189: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-11-18 16:02:08.984437: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 1 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:41:00.0 name: NVIDIA RTX A6000 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.8GHz coreCount: 84 deviceMemorySize: 47.54GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 715.34GiB/s
2021-11-18 16:02:08.984452: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-11-18 16:02:08.986983: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
2021-11-18 16:02:08.987017: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
2021-11-18 16:02:09.009829: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-11-18 16:02:09.009989: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-11-18 16:02:09.010322: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.11
2021-11-18 16:02:09.010867: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.11
2021-11-18 16:02:09.010951: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2021-11-18 16:02:09.011082: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-11-18 16:02:09.011414: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-11-18 16:02:09.011757: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-11-18 16:02:09.012031: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-11-18 16:02:09.012257: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1
2021-11-18 16:02:09.012704: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-11-18 16:02:09.171706: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-11-18 16:02:09.171957: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:2c:00.0 name: NVIDIA RTX A6000 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.8GHz coreCount: 84 deviceMemorySize: 47.54GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 715.34GiB/s
2021-11-18 16:02:09.172011: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-11-18 16:02:09.172207: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 1 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:41:00.0 name: NVIDIA RTX A6000 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.8GHz coreCount: 84 deviceMemorySize: 47.54GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 715.34GiB/s
2021-11-18 16:02:09.172259: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-11-18 16:02:09.172484: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-11-18 16:02:09.172706: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-11-18 16:02:09.172929: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-11-18 16:02:09.173118: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1
2021-11-18 16:02:09.173152: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-11-18 16:02:09.668270: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1258] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-11-18 16:02:09.668312: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1264]      0 1 
2021-11-18 16:02:09.668317: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1277] 0:   N Y 
2021-11-18 16:02:09.668321: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1277] 1:   Y N 
2021-11-18 16:02:09.668600: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-11-18 16:02:09.668881: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-11-18 16:02:09.669121: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-11-18 16:02:09.669358: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-11-18 16:02:09.669588: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-11-18 16:02:09.669816: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1418] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 46718 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA RTX A6000, pci bus id: 0000:2c:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
2021-11-18 16:02:09.670168: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-11-18 16:02:09.670374: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1418] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 46101 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: NVIDIA RTX A6000, pci bus id: 0000:41:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 36, in <module>
    model = object_detector.create(train_data=train_data, model_spec=spec, validation_data=validation_data, epochs=10000, batch_size=1, train_whole_model=True)
  File "/home/dev/Tensorflow/workspace/tpu_vision/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/task/object_detector.py", line 287, in create
    object_detector.train(train_data, validation_data, epochs, batch_size)
  File "/home/dev/Tensorflow/workspace/tpu_vision/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/task/object_detector.py", line 139, in train
    raise ValueError('The size of the train_data (%d) couldn\'t be smaller '
ValueError: The size of the train_data (0) couldn't be smaller than batch_size (1). To solve this problem, set the batch_size smaller or increase the size of the train_data.
```

If I comment out everything below the print statements in the code, we get the following:

```
(venv) dev@trainingpc:~/Tensorflow/workspace/tpu_vision$ python3 train.py 
2021-11-18 15:46:17.698405: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
train count: 0
validation count: 0
test count: 0
```

So to me, it looks like maybe the Dataloader functions are not working as intended, but I have tried my hardest to make sure that my data is all correct. I'm really struggling to find what could be wrong here. Any advice would be well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and my solution is that the dir paths are wrong.
Take

```
test_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc("C:\project\study\AI\face_detect\test_set\image_dir","C:\project\study\AI\face_detect\test_set\Annotations",['licheng','chengjin','lipeng'])
```

as example, and size of `test_data` is `0` until I change to

```
test_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc("C:\\project\\study\AI\\face_detect\\test_set\\image_dir","C:\\project\\study\\AI\\face_detect\\test_set\\Annotations",['licheng','chengjin','lipeng'])
```

I don't know if it's useful for you.

Comment: It took me a while to see the difference, but you're just doubling every backslash right? I guess that's a solution for a related problem on Windows, though probably not for OP since they're using Linux-style filenames with `/` instead of backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

OP is using Linux and it seems that the [DataLoader.from_pascal_voc()](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/python/tflite_model_maker/object_detector/DataLoader#from_pascal_voc) function requires the image and annotations directory string without trailing slashes on Linux. For example:

```
train_images_dir = '/home/dev/Tensorflow/workspace/tpu_vision/tpu_images/training/images'
train_annotations_dir = '/home/dev/Tensorflow/workspace/tpu_vision/tpu_images/training/annotations'
```

Now when you call from_pascal_voc(), you should have data:

```
train_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(train_images_dir, train_annotations_dir, label_map=label_map)
```